# How to find Open Office installation path programmatically in Java

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I am exporting UML diagrams in Open Office Draw using Java UNO Runtime Reference Api in Open Office. Initially I tried to connect Open Office using Bootstrap.bootstrap() method but it resulted in "No office executable found exception". Then according to the post [No office executable found exception while connecting to OpenOffice through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157644/no-office-executable-found-exception-while-connecting-to-openoffice-through-java) , I downloaded bootstrapconnector.jar and it worked fine for me. But in this case the user has to provide the path of the of the Open Office installation and my requirement is to connect to the Open Office instance by programmatically finding the installation path. One method I know is by means of working with WinRegistry but in this case I think that the registry key may change with underlying OS. Therefore it would be a great help if someone can suggest me some other method of achieving this.

Comment: Can you read the path from environment variables of Operating System.

Comment: Yes I can read the path from environment variables.

Comment: I would use default installation path for Windows/Linux. And if there's no OpenOffice installed, then I would ask user to specify this path in application settings.