# Error While Loading Document using OpenOffice SDK in JAVA

Tags: java, sdk, openoffice.org, uno

I'm trying to Load a document using OpenOffice SDK in JAVA. I'm Using `XComponentContext xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap()`, and trying to get the remote office component context of OpenOffice through Java. But it raises the exception `no office executable`.

I have attached my JAVA code, openOffice SDK path, and Java JDK path. The version of OpenOffice is `4.1.14`, machine is `MacOS x86_64` and `Java version 8`

Path of OpenOffice sdk in my local:
[image: Path of OpenOffice sdk in my local]

Error message: no office executable found
[image: Error message: no office executable found]

Location of OpenOffice SDK - `/Users/madhup/Desktop/OpenOffice_SDK`

Java JDK Path - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac`

zshrc profile:
[image: zshrc profile]

Java code:

```
import com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue;
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap;
import com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader;
import com.sun.star.lang.XComponent;
import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime;

import com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext;
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.BootstrapException;
public class LoadDocument {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BootstrapException {
        try {
            XComponentContext  xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap();

            com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();

            Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext(
                    "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

            XComponentLoader xCompLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XComponentLoader.class, oDesktop);

            String documentURL = "file:///Users/path_to_file/hello.odt";

            PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[0];

            XComponent xComponent = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(
                    documentURL, "_blank", 0, loadProps);

            if (xComponent != null) {
zshrc profile paths                System.out.println("Document loaded successfully.");
                xComponent.dispose();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to load the document.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Pom file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
            <artifactId>unoil</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
            <artifactId>juh</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
            <artifactId>jurt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
            <artifactId>ridl</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openoffice</groupId>
            <artifactId>officebean</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jeremysolarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I've already explored, set the SDK path, and added the classpath as mentioned in [No office executable found exception while connecting to OpenOffice through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157644/no-office-executable-found-exception-while-connecting-to-openoffice-through-java/59337721#59337721) and still getting the error.

Please help in resolving this problem.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, logs, errors, or other text; see [ask]. Speaking of: what error do you get exactly? Can you [edit] your question and add the error, maybe with stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Adding soffice path]

Add the path of the soffice in your project dependency, and it will work. In my case it was `/opt/Libreoffice7.6/program/`